# How to test related objects for equality in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, compare

I have following class hierarchy representing DNS:

```
class CZone {
    string                  m_Name;
    vector<RecordSurrogate> m_Records;
public:
                        CZone       ( string name ) : m_Name(name) {};
    bool                Add         ( const CRecord & );
    bool                Del         ( CRecord & );
    vector<CRecord>     Search      ( const string & ) const;
    void                Print       ( ostream & os ) const;
    friend ostream &    operator<<  ( ostream & os, const CZone & );
};
```

With *Add()* and *Del()* methods I would like to check whether there is record with given name in *m_Records* already present. I can’t use *typeid* here, however I can recognize different records with value returned by *Type()*.

I wrote `bool CZone::recEqual(const CRecord &lhs, const CRecord &rhs) const` medhod but got stuck with casting complaints like

> No matching conversion for static_cast from 'const CRecord' to 'const CRecA'

for this construct:

```
bool CRecA::isEqual( const CRecord & rhs ) const {
    return ( m_Name == rhs.m_Name && m_IP == static_cast<const CRecA>(rhs) . m_IP );
}
```

---

Base class:

```
class CRecord {
protected:
    string      m_Name;
public:
                            CRecord     ( void ) = default;
                            CRecord     ( string & name ) : m_Name(name) {}
                string      Name        ( void ) const { return m_Name; }
    virtual     string      Type        ( void ) const = 0;
    virtual    ~CRecord                 ( void ) {};
};
```

Derived classes:

```
class CRecA : public CRecord {
    CIPv4       m_IP;
public:
                CRecA       ( void ) = default;
    string      Type        ( void ) const { return "A"; }
    ostream &   operator << ( ostream & os ) const;
    CRecord *   copy        ( void ) const;

};

class CRecMX : public CRecord {
    string      m_Server;
    int         m_Prio;
public:
                CRecMX      ( void ) : m_Prio(0) {};
                CRecMX      ( string name, string server, int prio ) :
                    CRecord::CRecord(name), m_Server(server), m_Prio(prio) {}
    string      Type        ( void ) const { return "MX"; }
    ostream &   operator << ( ostream & os ) const;
    CRecord *   copy        ( void ) const;
};
```

Surrogate class:

```
class RecordSurrogate {
public:
                        RecordSurrogate ( void );
                        RecordSurrogate ( const CRecord & );
                       ~RecordSurrogate ( void );
                        RecordSurrogate ( const RecordSurrogate & );
    RecordSurrogate &   operator=       ( const RecordSurrogate & );
    string              Name            ( void ) const;
    string              Type            ( void ) const;
private:
    CRecord * rp;
};
```

Comment: That's what I'd call _'overformatted'_ code ...

Comment: _'but got stuck with casting complaints.'_ Which ones in particular? (I smelled it from my guts, there's something wrong with this question)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ e.g. No matching conversion for static_cast from 'const CRecord' to 'const CRecA' for this construct:
`bool CRecA::isEqual( const CRecord & rhs ) const {
    return ( m_Name == rhs.m_Name && m_IP == static_cast<const CRecA>(rhs) . m_IP );
}`

Comment: @mr-tao Edit your question to add essential additional information please! Putting such in comments is pretty useless!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the question is about general approach to comparison of related objects, what kind of logic goes to parent and how to handle comparison itself in derived classes with respect to necessary(?) `static_cast<>`s. I tried to put essential parts of code to original question and I doubt that pouring more overformated code would make it any clearer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Gave a hint you **really** should take to heart, because your additional code contains the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional code in the comments shows a mistake:

```
bool CRecA::isEqual(const CRecord& rhs) const
{
    return m_Name == rhs.m_Name && m_IP == static_cast<const CRecA>(rhs).m_IP;
}
```

You try to cast a `CRecord const&`to a `CRecA const`, which is incorrect. You need to cast it to `CRecA const&` instead.

The reason for this is quite simple: You wish to *interpret* the *original* object as its derived class - and not convert a `CRecord` object to a `CRecA` object.